# What is the diffference between HSM and PTS-approved point-of-interaction device?

Tags: pci-dss, hsm

**According to PCI-DSS requirement 3.5.2:**

We should store secret keys in a cryptographic device.

***Cryptographic devices:***

1.HSM

2.PTS-approved point of interaction device

My questions:

I have some knowledge about HSM and it encrypts the KEK using Master key. Also read about Thales HSM and I'm aware about it. But when I was looking into PTS, I can't understand it.

1. **What is PTS and is that a device like a HSM?**
2. **How does PTS differs from HSM?**
3. Which is the **best practice among HSM and PTS**?

Answer (score 2):

Very, very simple and in very simple words:

1. [**HSM**: is an appliance that manages keys.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) 
   [image: HSM Applicane]
2. **PTS**: is basically a card reader which allows you to enter a PIN number. 
   [image: PTS Device]

I forgot to "actually" answer the other two questions but I guess that an image is worth a thousand words =)

Comment: What you show is a PoS (Point of Sales), not a PTS. PTS is the name of the PCI spec that applies to PoS (and PoI in general).

Comment: @Gilles I believe he refers to the so called in the PCI-DSS PTS-dev, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @kiBytes Could you please confirm that second image you have mentioned for PTS is POS or PTS....does POS and PTS are same

Comment: PTS by itself means  "PIN transaction security", but when you are referring to the "devices", then they are usually called point of interaction, I believe that if you are comparing HSM and PTS I believe you are referring to PTS devices, and the point of sales you see in the picture is a good example of a PTS-dev.